# What are the pet terms for mother/father in US Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, estados-unidos, parentesco

In English, we have pet terms for mother and father. For example:
Mom, Dad, Mummy, Daddy, Mamma, Papa

In Spanish, they have madre/padre. But do they have any pet terms as well?
Does it vary between Spanish speakers in Spain and Hispanic speakers in America?

Edit: Ideally, I am looking for terms used by children primarily in America (USA). The most common ones.

Comment: This is a very broad question, as there are dozens (or more!) of regional variants. Can you focus your questions, perhaps by asking about a specific region? Listing all the possible pet names for parents will be impossible.  See [this meta post](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1408/12) for additional guidance. Please comment or flag for moderator attention after you have edited the question, and I will promptly re-open it.

Comment: By "America" do you mean all of Latin America, or do you mean the US?  All of Latin America is incredibly broad still. I'm assuming you mean the US, and have tagged accordingly, and reopened.

Comment: Yes, USA. I have updated the post.

Comment: I have seen that you asked the same question in another website.  forums.tomisimo.org/showthread.php?p=153842

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spain we use "madre" and "padre" when you refer to your parents (or somebody else's parents).

> Mi padre le ha regalado a mi madre un collar por su cumpleaños.
>
> Tu padre está un poco loco Juan.
>
> El padre de Luis es muy estricto; la madre un poco menos.

We call then "papá" and "mamá" when addressing directly to them or when talking about them with our siblings.

> Papá, ¿qué hay para cenar?
>
> Mamá, papá quiere saber dónde has puesto sus revistas.
>
> (Talking to my brother or sister) Ayer papá y mamá me echaron la bronca por llegar tarde.

There is also "papi" and "mami" (daddy, mamma/mammy), but they sound so cheesy that only small kids would use it.

I noticed that here in the States, where I live, people would say "My dad...". In Spain we use "Mi padre...". I think that some Latin American countries would use "Mi papá..." but in Spain saying "Mi papá...", unless you are a toddler, sounds like if you were saying "My daddy..." in English (little cultural differences).

I have heard many speakers from different Latin American countries use "papá" and "mamá" to refer to their parents to others, but I'm not sure if this is due to an influence of being in an English speaking country where they constantly hear "My dad..." of if it is also to norm in their own countries.

You could also use "papaíto" and even "mamaíta", but as with "papi" and "mami" only small children (or cheesy young adults) would use these terms.

Comment: Extending on this answer. At least in Argentina, it's common to address your parents just as "ma" and "pa". Also, it's becoming more common here to refer to your parents as "viejos"

I the US, "My old lady" would mean your wife. In Argentina it would mean your mom.

"Visité a mis viejos" --> lit. "I visited my old people" --> I visited my parents.

Comment: @Mauricio, "pet terms" significa en este caso "término cariñoso". No tiene nada que ver con mascotas. "Pet" puede ser un sustantivo (mascota), un verbo (acariciar) o un adjetivo (que denota algo a lo que tienes especial cariño). En la propia pregunta el OP pone de ejemplos: "Mom, Dad, Mummy, Daddy, Mamma, Papa" que son términos cariñosos para referirte a tus progenitores en inglés, no a tus mascotas. El OP busca equivalentes en español, porque sólo conoce "madre/padre" para referirse a los padres. **No** busca la manera de referirse a un animal de compañía que tiene cachorros.

Comment: @Diego Ahora entiendo. Gracias. _comentarios eliminados_

Comment: @Mauricio, gracias a ti por las buenas formas. A veces la gente critica de forma no constructiva, o simplemente dice "no es del todo correcto" y te planta un _downvote_ en lugar de ayudar a ampliar o mejorar la calidad de una respuesta. Así que gracias por la actitud positiva y cuestionar el contenido de la respuesta de forma educada y constructiva. :-)

Comment: @Diego Gracias por su comentario :). Por cierto, estaba leyendo una vez mas la pregunta y me acordé de la película _Monsters inc._ ya que al final _no hay spoilers_, un niño en el campo llama a su progenitora como _amá._ Dice así: _amá... se metió otro pejelagarto!..._, para el padre he escuchado _apá_. Este tipo de nombres también podría aplicarlos a su respuesta, pero no tengo fuentes o referencias. (Otras abreviaciones son _má_ y _pá_) _supongo que como Cletus_ personaje de _Los Simpsons_.

Comment: I have heard both `Mami` and `Papi` used in the latin dance scene in the US by both dance teachers and/or DJ's.  I never really did like those terms - and that was before I learnt what they were!

Comment: @PeterM, I agree. "Mami" and "Papi" have completely different connotations when a toddler uses them to refer to his/her parents and when adults use it to "_catcall_" other adults. I don't like it either how the term sounds when used in this way, but might be a cultural thing.

Answer (score 3):

The US spanish has variations. The main ones are Mexican Spanish, and Caribbean Spanish (Cuban, Dominican, Puerto Rican):

In Mexico there are some words to adress parents:

> *Mamá* and *papá* (*papás* for both): These are the main words in every day speech in every place you are, even with your boss at job.
>
> *Ma* and *pa* (mom and dad): Normal pet term for adressing your parents
>
> *Jefa* and *jefe* (litteraly boss, *jefes* for both): Another form, pretty common but not everyone uses this.
>
> *Mami* and *papi* (mommy and daddy, *papis* for both): Normal for toddlers and to add a childish touch to your speech. "Hijo de papi o mami" is for someone who depends a lot of his parents, or is rich.
>
> *Madre* and *padre* (Mother and father): These words sound too formal, it feels as if a character from a soup opera were talking. These are the formar words for thw written Spanish (you can say *mamá* to your boss but you can't write that in a letter, it's necessary the word "madre"). These words are commonly used to adress kids, especially parents for their children, but always as "mi padre" or "mi madre". And it's also used adress elder people "Dígame madre qué necesita.".

In other countries as Republica Dominicana i've heard:

> *Mai* and *pai* (mom and dad)

Depends on country of origin of people.

Answer (score 3):

In Puerto Rico it's not uncommon for people to use "mami" and "papi" into adulthood when speaking to someone who is friends or related to them as well. In public we would just use "mamá" or "papá" and "madre" and "padre" are more formal for us, like how "father" and "mother" are in English. We also use "ma/mai" and "pa/pai", which is usually used between young people from tweens to young adults in their 20s.

Sort of a sidebar here, I noticed that amongst relatives Mexicans will say "mi mamá/amá" "mi papá/apá" to thir brothers/sisters which I find a little odd. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: No, but it's a feature of German too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common terms in the US (although most of my experience is in Mexico) would be «mamá» and «papá», and some slight variations such as «mami» or «papi».  But every time I hear the latter I'm reminded of the part of the  Will Smith song [*Miami*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwBS6QGsH_4&t=1m41s) where they say

> ¡Ay, papi!

Answer (score 2):

I have heard and use "amá" and "apá".

Comment: Why is this answer getting negative scores? The words are indeed used very commonly in northwestern Mexico (Baja California, Sonora, Sinaloa) and Southern California. Even more commonly than papá and mamá. Like “ma” and “pa” they’re a contraction of these but without dropping the first “a”. I would only recommend Eric to elaborate on the regional and colloquial usage of the words.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @diego said you can use `madre` and `padre` when referring to your parents.

For example:

> Mi madre es bonita
>
> Mi padre es gordo.

Other ways could be "mama" and "papa", "pa" and "ma", and "mamá" and "papá"

Answer (score 1):

In Baja California, I've often heard "mi amá" in the third person and "má" in the second. For father/dad I wasn't paying attention, or else I've forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Where I live we refer to our mom with ma' (from mamá) or jefa. With dads you can say pa' or jefe. Also , where I'm from, we do call our moms mamacita and our dads (papacito) but its usually when you want something back.
For example:
*You're in a store with your mom and you see something that you want this is how that conversation would go*
"Mamacita bonita, could you buy me this, please?